# incorrect syntax near error

Tags: sql

I have problem with this code the error is incorrect syntax near ,., this the code please help.

```
String sql = @"select
            C_Date,
            L_UID,
            min(C_Time) as [login],
            max(C_Time) as [logout]
   from
            tEnter
   where
            L_UID = "+txtEmpName+"
       and
            C_Date between '" + dtfrom + "' and '" + dtto + "'
   group by
            C_Date,
            L_UID";
```

Comment: there isnt a '.' in the code you have provided

Comment: `[login]` is an invalid identifier in (standard) SQL

Comment: You have not enclosed txtEmpName into quotes.

Comment: how explain more

Comment: Suggestion: replace the sql-standards tag with the tag for the dbms you're actually using. (sql-server?)

Comment: could please rewrite correct code with quotation  I wrote this code in sql query and it works but here I change some parameter like textbox

Comment: Your question shows minimal effort. Stack Overflow is not a debugging service for those who can't be bothered to format their code correctly or provide a working example. Additionally I suspect your code is highly susceptible to SQL injection attacks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: Is this ... A debugging request? Yes, Minimal? Yes, Complete? No, Verifiable, No. Therefore this is not a valid question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess: `txtEmpName` is a text field, perhaps 'Wile E. Coyote'.
The way the string is constructed, `txtEmpName` needs to be enquoted, and it isn't. The SQL parser catches the problem when it hits the unquoted `.`